# Summing a certain index values in lists within a list grouped by the first index value from each list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists as follows,

`data = [[1, 2],[1, 10], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 2], [8, 3], [3,2]]`

I want to group the inside lists by their first position value and then sum the second position values wherever there is a match like in the snippet below,

`result = [[1,16],[2,5],[3,2],[8,3]]`

how do I achieve this in pure python please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20groupby#itertools.groupby) to group on the first value in each sublist, and then `sum` the second value in each grouped list:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [[1, 2],[1, 10], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 2], [8, 3], [3,2]]

groups = groupby(data, key=lambda v:v[0])
result = [[i, sum(v[1] for v in g)] for i, g in groups]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 16], [2, 5], [8, 3], [3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` for that to collect all the inner list first item and all these lists second items to a list and sum all of them.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [[1, 2],[1, 10], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 2], [8, 3], [3,2]]
res_dist = defaultdict(list)
for i in data:
    res_dist[i[0]].append(i[1])
print(sorted([[k, sum(v)] for k, v in res_dist.items()], key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Output

```
[[1, 16], [2, 5], [3, 2], [8, 3]]
```